# Add each occurrence of text between two strings to an array bash

Tags: arrays, string, bash, sed

I need to parse **each occurrence** of text between QUESTION NO: and the first answer: A. without including the lines that contain Question NO: or A. So just the question appears. I'd like to append EACH matching result/question to an **array** in BASH, so that each question can be retrieved using something like (for question 16): `echo ${questions[16]}.`

My test.txt looks like this for example:

```
QUESTION NO: 16
Which of the following is the correct answer
based on a supplied criteria for the values in the records?
A. LIMIT
B.....
C..
```

The command:

```
sed -n '/NO:/,/A./{//!p}' test.txt > justquestions.txt
```

...seems to generate the correct output, however i am unable to get this sed command to append each result to an array in memory. I keep getting the whole output so that each question cannot be tracked by an array number.

How do I append **each** match to an array something like `questions+=( "${p}" )` from the sed/or similar command output? Sometimes the question is **one line**, sometimes **multiple**, and the questions can **contain special characters** as well. THANKS!

If the multiple choice answers: A. B. C. D. E. are not present, since the question is a fill-in-the-blank, an incorrect line is appended to the array.

For example text:

```
QUESTION NO: 123
What is the best command ever (fill in the blank ____)?
Answer: reboot
```

echo ${Q_answer[4]} returns:

```
What is the best command ever (fill in the blank ____)? Answer: reboot
```

instead of expected:

```
What is the best command ever (fill in the blank ____)?
```

Maybe the "end_re=" could also stop at an occurrence of "Answer:" or any other text when not "A." I wonder if stopping at the "?" would be the best idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start_re='^[[:space:]]*QUESTION NO:[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]]+)$'
end_re='^[[:space:]]*(A[.]|Answer:)'

curr_q=       # track current question number
questions=( ) # initialize array

while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ $start_re ]]; then # if we see the start of a question
    curr_q=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}       # set the current question number
    continue                        # and don't process this line further
  fi
  if [[ $line =~ $end_re ]]; then   # if we see the end of a question
    curr_q=                         # clear the current question number
    continue                        # and don't process this line further
  fi
  if [[ $curr_q ]]; then                 # when a question number exists
    if [[ ${questions[$curr_q]} ]]; then # and we already have text for it
      questions[$curr_q]+=$'\n'"$line"   # append additional text after a newline
    else                                 # otherwise, if we have no existing content
      questions[$curr_q]=$line           # assign the line we just read outright
    fi
  fi
done
```

After running the above with your given question as input, `declare -p questions` emits the following state:

```
declare -a questions='([16]="Which of the following is the correct answer
based on a supplied criteria for the values in the records?")'
```

Comment: I'm sorry -- it still doesn't render where the newlines are. For instance, is `CORRECT TEXT` on the same line as `QUESTION NO: 9`? I can't tell from the comment, which is why I'm asking you to edit your follow-up *into the question itself*.

Comment: I can't reproduce that -- using the answer as currently given, and the exact text in the question, I don't have `Answer:` in the resulting `questions` array element.

Comment: Is it possible to generate multiple arrays using your example? With multiple start & end points. such as $start_re, $end_re, $start_re1, $end_re1, $start_re2, $end_re2, questions(), questions1() and questions2().

Comment: Of course. The only thing you'd need to change is the control flow, since you couldn't have a `continue` from one decision flow impact the other items under evaluation.

Comment: [additional related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38937295/expand-functionality-of-a-while-loop-to-generate-multiple-arrays-rather-than-one/)